# Is it possible to put a piece of code at the end of execution stack in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-events

For example I have many handlers on focus-out of a text box.
I want to focus-out  the text-box by code and run another code after the execution of all handlers.

-------update------

In my case I don't have any access to the event handlers. It’s an external module with its own UI. Actually I use Chromium Embedded Framework. Some of the modules on the web page save their data after focus-out.

Comment: Post your code please

Comment: You're probably going to want to use a [Promise](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise)

Comment: hmm... I'm pretty sure jQuery has event que code samples on it's site. Have you attempted to review this before posting?

Comment: So why not bind a new focusout handler (maybe using `.one()`) for this textbox just before triggering this event. The last bound handler will be the last one called. That's said, i guess you should read this: http://mywiki.wooledge.org/XyProblem

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is it possible to put a piece of code at the end of execution stack in JavaScript

No, because technically, you can only put stuff on top of the stack and not below it.

**However**, you can take advantage of the fact that after the execution stack clears, the engine takes a look at another piece of storage called the "callback queue" where callbacks of completed async operations wait for their turn to get executed.

---

## Timers

You can use timers. The way timers work is that timers, when the count completes, queues the callback in the callback queue. Like mentioned earlier, when the execution stack clears, the engine takes a look at the callback queue, picks up a callback and executes it. So technically, it's not being at the end of the stack, but you execute it *after the stack clears* which should look just about the same.

**However**, this is only if all other handlers execute synchronous code. If one of them does an async operation (like AJAX or timered stuff), JS will queue that AJAX callback the same way and you'll lose the effect. See it in action here: http://jsfiddle.net/w8brztL4/

---

## Bind Late

Another way you could do it is to unbind your handler for focus-out and rebind it. That way, it's registered last and will most likely execute last among attached handlers.

**However**, jQuery's execution order, as far as I remember is: all handlers bound on the element first to last, *then* the parent first to last, then to parent of parent first to last and so on. See it in action here: http://jsfiddle.net/rcc0c9em/ For maximum effectiveness, bind somewhere far and late, like on `document`.

Answer (score 0):

Most browsers have a function called `setImmediate(callback)` which queues the callback for execution immediately after the current event queue is empty.

For browsers that don't support it, you can get almost the same thing with `setTimeout(callback, 1)`.

Comment: `setImmediate` only exists in IE. "Most browsers" wouldn't be the best way to describe it.

Comment: Also, based on NodeJS docs, `setImmediate` callbacks fire *before* `setTimeout`/`setInterval`, which makes it a bad candidate for making stuff "last".

Comment: I embedded Chrome in my application so it doesn't work for me.